# Is T self adjoint and unitary?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, inner-products

Consider the Hilbert space $H=l^2 $over $\mathbb C$ .If $x\in l^2$,then $\displaystyle{ \sum_{i=1}^\infty}|x_k|^2<\infty$.If $x,y\in l^2$, the inner product is defined by $$\langle x,y\rangle=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_k\bar y_k$$.

Let $T:l^2\to l^2$ is defined by  $T(x_1,x_2...)=(x_1,\frac{x_2}{2},\frac{x_3}{3}....)$.

Is T self- adjoint and unitary ?

My thought:

I am not sure which criteria's  are necessary to show self-adjointness.I know T is self adjoint if $T=T^\star$

Again I found $\langle T(x),y\rangle=\langle (x_1,\frac{x_2}{2},\frac{x_3}{3}....), (y_1,y_2...)\rangle= \displaystyle{ \sum_{k=1}^\infty}\frac{x_k}{k}.\bar y_k$, I can't further proceed.

For unitary, $TT^\star=T^\star T=I$.

Please someone explain and give a brief idea how to solve this types of problems.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that a unitary operator preserves norms. Can you find an element $x\in\ell^2$ such that $\|Tx\|<\|x\|$? Regarding self-adjointness, just shift the $1/k$ from the left to the right factor in your computation of $\langle Tx,y\rangle$.

Comment: If I show T is bounded (strictly),then T is not unitary.Is it? and for the second after shifting 1/k, can i get $\langle x,T^\star(y)\rangle$?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by strictly bounded. Anyway, once you have computed $T^\ast$ it will be immediate that $T$ is not unitary. For the second part: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

**$T$, Self-adjoint?**

$\langle x,y\rangle=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_k\bar y_k$

$\langle x,Tx\rangle=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_k\cdot\bar {\frac{x_k}{k}}=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{|x_k|^2}{k}$

$\langle Tx,x\rangle=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {\frac{\bar x_k}{k}\cdot x_k}=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{|x_k|^2}{k}$

Thus T is self-adjoint.

**$T$, unitary?**

Since $T$ is self-adjoint, if $T$ were unitary then $T$ it is its own inverse so that $T^2=I$

$T^2(x)=T(T(x))=T(x_1,\frac{x_2}{2},\frac{x_3}{3},.....)=(x_1,\frac{x_2}{4},\frac{x_3}{9},......)\ne (x_1,x_2,x_3,.....)$

Thus $T$ is not unitary.

Comment: While it is true that $\langle Tx,x\rangle=\langle x,Tx\rangle$ for all $x\in H$ implies that $T$ is self-adjoint (in complex Hilbert spaces), the proof of this fact is certainly longer than just writing out $\langle Tx,y\rangle$ and $\langle x,Ty\rangle$.

Comment: But for a given and particular sesquilinear form, the proof is direct.